# Can't get form fields from button action (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I'm using a modal window with a form along with a 'save settings' button to trigger JavaScript/AJAX calls to my ASP.NET Core back-end (eventually). When I inspect the elements using Chrome I can see all the properties however my saved variable from `.serializeArray()` only produces the `__RequestVerificationToken`.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnSaveSettings", function () {
    var savedSettings = $('form#frmSaveSettings').serializeArray();
    console.log(savedSettings);
});
```

[image: Console output]

[image: Form properties]
**HTML:**

```
<form asp-page-handler="SaveSettings" class="form-horizontal" id="frmSaveSettings" method="post">
<fieldset> //most elementes removed for clarity!
    <legend>Edit network node</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Domain name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="spanPartitionKey" readonly />
            </div>
        </div>
</fieldset> 
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div align="left" class="col-sm-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete node</button>
            </div>
            <div align="right" class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveSettings">Save settings</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on the above, I would expect `savedSettings` to contain the value of the form control (along with the anti-forgery token). I have another modal form in the same page that works fine however I'm not scraping the form elements the same way; rather I'm referencing them by their `id` tag.

Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for
>   successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in
>   particular the element cannot be disabled and **must contain a name
>   attribute**.

The `<input>` element in your sample code does not have a `name` attribute, set that and serializeArray() will include it.

Source: [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Answer (score 1):

As per [Documentation of $().serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method, it serializes by `name`, not by `id`. So you just need to add proper `name` attribute to each input.